# Android json objects to array list in Parcelable class

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I don't know of the title is very accurate, but let me explain what I want.
I am having this long JSONObject (sadly it's not an array and I can't loop through it) with many other JSONObjects inside of it with similar elements (id, name, icon), and when I read through an element it writes its value in a separate class with implemented Parcelable.
Here is what my Parcelable class look like before I explain further:

```
public class ItemsInfo implements Parcelable {

    public int itemId;
    public String itemName, itemIcon;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(itemName);
        dest.writeString(itemIcon);
        dest.writeInt(itemId);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ItemsInfo > CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ItemsInfo >() {

        @Override
        public ItemsInfo createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            ItemsInfo ei = new ItemsInfo();
            ei.itemName = source.readString();
            ei.itemIcon = source.readString();
            ei.itemId = source.readInt();
            return ei;
        }

        @Override
        public ItemsInfo [] newArray(int size) {
            return new ItemsInfo [size];
        }
    };
}
```

what I want is everytime it reads through a JSONObject with the similar elements, to write them with an ArrayList in the String itemName, so later I can access a given item by only a index or something, and not to have to make separate strings and integers for every different item, like itemName1, itemName2, itemName3..... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to simplify `JSON` parsing. To convert your `JSONObject` to a *Key-Value* mapping, you can use this:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();//this will contain your JSONObject strings
Map<String, ?> data = null;
try {
    JSONObject json;//this references your JSONObject
    data = $.map(json);
    
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("JSON", "Malformed JSON Object");
}
```

Then, to loop through each element, just do this:

```
if (data != null) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        items.add(entry.value().toString());
    }
}
```

Now your `List` *items* is populated with the String representation of your `JSONObejct`s. Later, if you want to parse this JSON, just do:

```
int index = 2;//the index of the JSONObject you want
try {
    Map<String, ?> data = $.map(new JSONObject(items.get(2)));
    //now iterate the map
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();//something wrong with your JSON string
}
```

Comment: @БориславМинчев, that is part of the *droidQuery* library, which is modeled after the *Javascript* library *jQuery*. *droidQuery* is all pure *Android Java*. Simply add the library *jar* to your *libs* folder, then import *self.philbrown.droidQuery.**;